# Integrating jointjs with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jointjs

I need to render joint js as a directive in angularjs.I am new to both the frameworks.Currently im rendering it using div. How do i do it using angular directive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="jointjsApp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/joint.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="lib/joint.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<title>Test</title>
<body>
    <div id="myholder"> </div>
</body>
<script>
    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#myholder'),
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        model: graph
    });

    var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });

    var rect2 = rect.clone();
    rect2.translate(300);

    var link = new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: rect.id },
        target: { id: rect2.id }
    });

    graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
</script>
</html>
```

How to i do the same using an angular directive

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I inject JointJS as an AngularJS module like any other library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414286/can-i-inject-jointjs-as-an-angularjs-module-like-any-other-library)